# How to enable the server side entry feature for Cosmos db using Bicep template

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-bicep

I have not defined anything related to the features in my script and not sure what to be included to enable the "ServerSideEntry" feature for a cosmos db.

Below one is my script:

```
// Cosmos Account
resource CosmosDbAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-04-15' = {
  name: CosmosDbAccountName
  location: location
  kind: 'MongoDB'
  properties: {
    databaseAccountOfferType: CosmosDbOfferType
    locations: CosmosLocations
    enableAutomaticFailover: CosmosAutomaticFailover
    isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled: true
    enableAnalyticalStorage: true
    virtualNetworkRules: [for item in VirtualNetworkRules: {
      id: resourceId(item.SubscriptionId, item.resourcegroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', item.virtualnetwork, item.subnet)
    }]
    minimalTlsVersion: 'Tls12'
    consistencyPolicy: {
      defaultConsistencyLevel: defaultConsistencyLevel
    }
    capabilities: [
      {
        name: 'EnableMongo'
      }
    ]
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just looking for a similar thing, for server side retry feature.

Comment: so you need to create triggers/ user defined function etc ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific property existed for server-side functionality implementation. Usually, to add any properties under a cosmos account, it should be included in `capabilities` block itself. But when I tried to add in my environment, it showed an error
`"server-side functionality doesn't exist"`.

[image]

Alternatively, as a workaround, you can use this [server-side functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/manage-with-bicep#azure-cosmos-db-container-with-server-side-functionality) bicep template to meet your requirements.

I tried the required sample code in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully as shown.

*Note: Refer to the above document for complete code.*

```bash
param cosmosaccount string = 'xxxx'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param primaryRegion string = 'eastus'
param defaultConsistencyLevel string = 'Session'
param systemManagedFailover bool = true
param database string = 'xxxx'

var consistencyPolicy = {
  Eventual: {
    defaultConsistencyLevel: 'Eventual'
  }
}
var locations = [
  {
    locationName: primaryRegion
    failoverPriority: 0
    isZoneRedundant: false
  }
]

resource account 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-05-15' = {
  name: cosmosaccount
  location: location
  kind: 'MongoDB'
  properties: {
    consistencyPolicy: consistencyPolicy[defaultConsistencyLevel]
    locations: locations
    databaseAccountOfferType: 'Standard'
    enableAutomaticFailover: systemManagedFailover
  }
}

resource database 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2022-05-15' = {
  parent: account
  name: database
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: database
    }
  }
}
```

*Output:*

[image]